# Existing PHP Session Assigned to other client

Tags: nginx, php, apache-2.4

I have a 64RAM, 32vCPU VPS with Apache and Nginx as reverse proxy.
Suddenly after a traffic increase some of the clients everything works perfect. Traffic is being handled decently, the problem is that some of the client are getting someone else session and since the website login system is based on Sessions they suddenly find themselves logged into some other account.

Would Nginx be a reason of this problem? I checked the Real ip to be the client one in my website and it looks fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you use caching?

Comment: It is the default config of Engintron for nginx

Comment: i am not familiar with it, but you should recheck caching configuration for it. also, if posssible, post configuration here for us to inspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by nginx proxy micro caching. Look up custom_rules file and see option $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC

This should be set to 1